# How to find difference between two dates with time in custom format in hours?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Cell A1 has date 06/22/2016 11:17:00 AM IST and cell B1 has date 06/22/2016 11:38:00 AM IST

Both this dates are in custom format.

I have to find the difference between these two dates in hours.

For this i am using below formula
C1=(LEFT(B1,22)-LEFT(A1,22))*24

Now i am getting answer 0.35
This is difference between two dates in hours.
But this is wrong. Answer should be 0.27

Don't know what is going wrong.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference seems to be 38 - 17 = 21 minutes, which is 21 / 60 = 0.35 hours. Exactly what Excel says.

What makes you think 0.27 would be correct??

Comment: Thanks for your help. 21 was minutes. Thanks a lot :)